# finding the distance between a node and the root of a tree

Tags: java, tree

i'm creating a method to find the distance between a particular node and the root of the tree it is in, and i wanted to verify if this is the simplest way to do so. i was slightly worried that holder would become the original node, and thus as i am moving up the tree, i am pulling said node up with me.

```
    public int distanceToRoot(Node node)
{
    Node holder= node;
    int distance=0;
    if (node.getParent()==null)
    {
        distance=0;
    }
    else
    {
        while (holder.getParent() !=null)
            {
            holder=holder.getParent();
            distance++;
            }
    }
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: The entire `if-then-else` structure is unnecessary.  You'll get the same result with just the loop.

Comment: sweet, i was just worried that making the nodes equivlant would link the memory addresses similar to if you do it with arrays, and then running the loop would ruin the tree

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
public int distanceToRoot(Node node)
{
    if (node == null) 
        /* what do you want to do in this case */;
    int d = 0;
    for(Node p=node.getParent(); p!=null; p=p.getParent()) d++;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via recursion.  Starting from any child node, traverse upwards to parent node.  When it is found, return the distance.

```
public int distanceToRoot(Node node, int distance){
    // If no parent it must be the root, return whatever value distance currently is
    if (node.getParent()==null) return distance;

    // Otherwise, recurse passing in this node's parent and current distance plus 1
    return distanceToRoot(node.getParent(), distance + 1 );
}
```

It should be called with an initial distance of zero

```
int dist = distanceToRoot(aNode, 0);
```

Comment: Remember that just because recursion is "cool" doesn't mean it's the best tool, even when it's a natural fit.  The best example of this is calculating Fibonacci numbers. While the _mathematical_ function is defined recursively, for large values a recursive implementation gobbles up huge amounts of stack space due to the dual branching at each value -- unless you add memoization of intermediate results at which point you're an order of magnitude more complex than a simple loop.

Comment: True.  But since it is tail-recursive, saving a stack frame isn't necessary as there is no need to return through them.

Comment: A tail-recursive fibonacci sequence is more efficient than a normal recursive version because the normal recursive version will need to recurse until the base case is met and then return through the stack frames to multiply by each frame's `n` value (i.e the first call to fibonacci function is the one that actually returns the solution).  In a tail-recursive function, when the base case is met, the answer is known without having to return through any previous stacks frames.

OP asked for simple so a recursive solution came to my mind.  I didn't know that recursion was thought to be "cool"